# Cursor won't change in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: unity, 14.04, compiz, cursor

I know there was an old bug back during Ubuntu 9.x where the cursor wouldn't change because of compiz. I am now running Ubuntu 14.04 and the bug has now decided to rear its ugly head again. I am using an old cursor that looked decent with a theme and I now switched themes and my current cursor doesn't look good with it. I tried changing it with unity tweak tool but when I apply the cursor, it won't change but it will use them in certain programs such as Firefox. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Firefox and a few other apps use GTK2/QT - if the cursor is only chnaged for gtk3 that may be part of the problem. Oh, and if this is a bug you may wish to report it ([how-to here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)).

Comment: It won't even switch back to DMZ White which is the default cursors in Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, switched cursor theme to Mac style then couldn't change it back by Unity tweak tool. but removing the new theme worked for me and managed to get the Dwz-white back again.

Answer (score 0):

Synergy was causing the issue for me.  Updating synergy to 1.6.2 from http://synergy-project.org/download/   resolved my issue.

Found this solution first mentioned here https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=313427#makechanges